# tkinter treeview change column font size

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tkinter.style

Right now i have this threecode:

```
tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=150)
tree.column("two", width=150)
tree.column("three", width=150)
tree.heading("one", text="Naar")
tree.heading("two", text="Spoor")
tree.heading("three", text="Vetrektijd")
tree['show'] = 'headings'
```

but what i want to do is change the font size to 20 of the three columns
But how can i do that?
Since on the internet i read something about Style() but that doesnt work in my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two solutions which jump to mind.

The first is the use of `Style()` as you pointed out, which will let us set the style of the `Treeview.Heading` text if we want to change that.

This looks something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=(None, 100))

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=150)
tree.column("two", width=150)
tree.column("three", width=150)
tree.heading("one", text="Naar")
tree.heading("two", text="Spoor")
tree.heading("three", text="Vetrektijd")
tree['show'] = 'headings'
```

This works by styling specific elements inside the widget. Let's break this down.

`style = ttk.Style()` tells tkinter that we are creating a style and we're storing it inside of the variable `style`.

`style.configure()` allows us to configure the style we just created.`

`"Treeview.Heading"` is the name of the element for the column headings.

`font=(None, 100)` is a "cheaty" way of increasing font size without having to change the font itself. If you wanted to change the font style substitute `None` with whichever font you wanted. Perhaps `Comic Sans MS`.

---

The other option is using a function tkinter has built in called `nametofont` which let's us mess with the fonts at a deeper level.

We can do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import nametofont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

#nametofont("TkHeadingFont").configure(size=100)

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=150)
tree.column("two", width=150)
tree.column("three", width=150)
tree.heading("one", text="Naar")
tree.heading("two", text="Spoor")
tree.heading("three", text="Vetrektijd")
tree['show'] = 'headings'
```

Which seems to achieve the same result, right?

What we're doing differently here is actually modifying the font that tkinter attributes to `TkHeadingFont` and telling it to change it's size to `100`. Meaning that if you were to use that font somewhere else it would also appear in the same style.

This involves having to declare `from tkinter.font import nametofont` at the top of your program however.

Either method achieves the same result aesthetically speaking.

Comment: Out of curiosity which method did you choose.