# How to change font of a single tkinter (ttk) treeview heading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to make a single ttk.treeview() column's heading bold in Python 3, and I can't figure out how to go about this. Thanks in advance!

In reference to this answer: [tkinter treeview change column font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932332/tkinter-treeview-change-column-font-size), unfortunately this only works for changing the fonts of all of the treeview headings.  I'm looking to change just the font of ONE heading. For context, I'm sorting by the column, and I'd like the column heading to be bold when it is the column doing the sorting.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932332/tkinter-treeview-change-column-font-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter treeview change column font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932332/tkinter-treeview-change-column-font-size)