# Change font in one column of tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, treeview

I would like to display a list of about 2500 fonts with 2 columns.  Column 1 with the font name and column 2 with a sample text styled with the font named in column 1 for that row.

I am trying to use tkinter treeview to do this.  I saw a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932332/tkinter-treeview-change-column-font-size) but the answer that was given only applied to column headers.

I am also open to suggestions for other widget structures to accomplish this.

Comment: Change the [font](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M75) attribute by applying a tag to the column and then [configuring the tag](https://python-forum.io/thread-36550.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for font_name in font_list:
    # create a tag for each font name in the list
    # the name of the font is the name of the tag
    my_treeview.tag_configure(font_name, font=font_name)
    # insert items into the treeview using the font_name tags
    my_treeview.insert(
        '',
        tk.END,
        values=(font_name, sample_text),
        tags=[font_name]
    )
    # the caveat here is that both columns will be in the new font
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if it doesn't give me control over individual cells it doesn't help me.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately I don't know if there is a way to accomplish what you're after. I suppose you could cheat and put two treeview widgets next to each other and bind them to the same scrollbar, but that's admittedly a hack.